# Objective C - Move UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have view with tab bar and with button to open side bar.

When the side bar is open, the tab bar stay without moving with the side bar.

The side bar is simply 2 views, one on the other in the same viewController.

Is it possible to move the tab bar with the upper view(side bar)?

[image]

Comment: Ok I'v found the answer in some website. to get the UITabBar frame: ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.frame And then I can just do like this: ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.frame.origin.x + 50, ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.frame.origin.y, ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.frame.size.width, ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 1):

With your solution you probably will need then to move all objects on the green field as you do with the tabbar. better way is to have 2 VC (scenes): one with the green field and tab bar, another one is a side menu. and animate the frame positions of the VCs (kind of left/right facebook menu animation), so all related objects will be moved including tabbar.

Comment: there are many examples of left/right menu on github and in internet. check the code there and try to implement your case.